# Error of connectivity with SQL Server in asp.net program

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, database-connection

I was working on my MVC project asp.net 6 in VS 2022 and I wanted to connect the project with the database, so I wrote this command:

```
Scaffold-Dbcontext "Server=DESKTOP-kd; Database=Gestion; Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Data
```

and when executing it displayed to me this error message:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on storing connection strings, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - La chaîne de certificats a été fournie par une autorité qui n’est pas approuvée.)
Error Number:-2146893019,State:0,Class:20
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - La chaîne de certificats a été fournie par une autorité qui n’est pas approuvée.)
```

I tried to add these `TrustServerCertificate=true; Encrypt=false;` in my connection string in appsettings but nothing changed. What can I try next?

I was working on my MVC project asp.net 6 in VS 2022 and I wanted to connect the project with the database so I wrote this command:

```
Scaffold-Dbcontext "Server=DESKTOP-LINA; Database=GestionSQLI; Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Data
```

I'm sure of the name of server and desktop. I checked it multiple times.

Comment: `Scaffold-Dbcontext "Server=DESKTOP-LINA; Database=GestionSQLI; Trusted_Connection=True; TrustServerCertificate=true; Encrypt=false;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Data` or better just get yourself a proper certificate

Answer (score -1):

"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=YourDatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}

//OR
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=YourDatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models

Comment: Good effort providing guidance! however, try to:
 - format code between quotes to make it more readable
 - provide some context for the code you post: what does it do, where is it fixing the problem, etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).